# IBM Watson + Java

Tags: java, oracle, ibm, watson

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dino_post_java;


import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.natural_language_classifier.v1.NaturalLanguageClassifier;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.natural_language_classifier.v1.model.Classification;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.natural_language_classifier.v1.model.ClassifyOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author Matheus Markies
 */
public class Text_Robot extends Thread{

    public static ArrayList<String> KeyWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void run(){

    //JSONObject vcap =new JSONObject(System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"));

   NaturalLanguageClassifier service = new NaturalLanguageClassifier();
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

    ClassifyOptions classifyOptions = new ClassifyOptions.Builder()
        .classifierId("<classifierId>")
        .text("Is it sunny?")
        .build();
    Classification classification = service.classify(classifyOptions).execute();

    System.out.println(classification);

    }

}
```

Não estou conseguindo usar o NaturalLanguageClassifier.
Quando tento executar o programa ele volta o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei usar o VCAP_SERVICES.json como mostra nesse [site](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-variables.html#vcapServices)

Mas não tive resultados.

Quando tento acessar o link usando o usuário e senha que eu coloquei, ele fala que o usuário e senha estão errados.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Passo 1:**

Segundo a mensagem de erro, você não está passando as credenciais corretamente `Exception in thread "Thread-5" ... Access denied due to invalid credentials`.

Tente executar os passos de acordo com a própria [documentação do Watson](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-classifier/getting-started.html?cm_mc_uid=62243582350015520646604&cm_mc_sid_50200000=35408361552064660483&cm_mc_sid_52640000=30347271552064660496#natural-language-classifier):

> **Etapa 1: efetue login, crie o serviço e obtenha suas credenciais**
>
> > Se você já souber suas credenciais para a instância de serviço do    Natural
> >     Language Classifier, ignore esta etapa.
>
> - Acesse o serviço Natural Language Classifier e inscreva-se para uma    conta grátis ou efetue login na conta do IBM Cloud.
> - Depois de efetuar login, na página Natural Language Classifier,    digite `Classifier-tutorial` no campo Nome do serviço para identificar
>     essa instância do serviço e clique em Criar.
> - Copie suas credenciais:
>
>   - **a.** Clique em Credenciais de serviço.
>   - **b.** Clique em Visualizar credenciais na seção "Credenciais de serviço".
>   - **c.** Copie os valores *username* e *password*.

**Passo 2:**

No erro também está indicando que pode ser uma falha em especificar o endpoint.
Verifique se está correto e de acordo com a [API do Watson](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-classifier)

**Passo 3:**

Pode ser de grande ajuda verificar códigos open-source de usuários que ja implementaram tais funções cito como exemplo: [NaturalLanguageClassifier javaSDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/natural-language-classifier/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/natural_language_classifier/v1/NaturalLanguageClassifier.java)

**Passo 4:**

Se mesmo assim não funcionar verifique os logs do erro e as linhas de código onde os erros estão aparecendo.